# Can we get two run outs in one ball?

Tags: rules, cricket

Suppose player1 is got runout and player2 is also out of the line then can we get player2's wicket too by hitting the stumps?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sd6yFyfrE2M

Comment: @Jon Mark Were both of them got out?

Comment: i thought so, i didn't know the ball is dead once a wicket is taken.

Comment: @JonMarkPerry please provide evidence they were both out.

Comment: @PhilipKendall; that's all i could find - i think i have seen 2 outs in one ball somewhere before, but i can't find it.

Comment: @PhilipKendall; the case i find amusing is if the non-receiving batsman dislodges his own wicket - are they out? in which case the receiving batsman could be bowled, the non-receiving batsman could dislodge his wicket...

Comment: Nope, because once again the ball would be dead as soon as the first batsman is out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. As soon as a batsman is out, the ball is dead so there is no way to get two run outs in one ball. The only exception is to get a "regular" run out on a ball, and then to run out the non-striker backing up ("Mankading") before the next ball is delivered.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sd6yFyfrE2M see video

Comment: I see the video, but I'm not sure what point you're trying to make - the comments on the video (if you ignore the usual YouTube spam) agree precisely with my answer.